# SSIS Source SQL Statement to include variables

Tags: ssis

In my work place's SQL Server 2008 set up, we have set up a database table called `DATE_RANGE_CONTROL` with two columns: `startDate` and `endDate` of data type DateTime. Our SSIS packages extract data from an Oracle Database for a set date range so most of our SQL code in the DB Source Editor takes the form of:

```
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,TRANSACTION_DATE
FROM SOURCE_DATABASE_TABLE
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

What I want to do is to set the `startDate` and `endDate` dynamically so that at the time of execution, the query gets the values from the `DATE_RANGE_CONTROL` table. I have looked at using the ***SQL Command from variable*** as an option but I cannot figure out how to feed the values of `startDate` and `endDate` from the `DATE_RANGE_CONTROL` table to the DB Source SQL command.

I have done something similar in the SQL SERVER 2000 DTS packages where I was setting the SQLCommand property of the data pump dynamically using the ACTIVEX script task. How do i do it in SSIS?

Comment: Create a variablle with type as string. And in variable properties click on expression, there you can use date stored in some other varibles to apply where condition.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a considerable amount of time on Google and looking through the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SSIS documentation, I have finally cracked it. So proud of myself. The solution is thus:

1. In SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio, create a new SSIS package.
2. Create 3 variables, I called mine `startDate`, `endDate` and `strDataSourceSQL`. Make sure they all have a scope level of Package and ensure thay have Data Types of `Int32`, `Int32` and `String` respectively..
3. On the Control Flow tab, drag a `Script Task` from the toolbox to the Control Flow pane. Right click it and choose edit from the pop up menu.
4. On the `Script` page, click on the ellipsis to the right of `ReadWriteVariables`. Tick the variables you created in step 1 i.e. `user::startDate`, `user::endtDate` and `user::strDataSourceSQL`. You can rename your script task on the `General page`. It is good practice.
5. On the `Script` page,click on the `Edit Script...` button to reveal a visual studio IDE pane with some pre-written code.
6. Make the following changes. At the top of the page, you will notice a few lines the import namespaces and classes to use. Edit the lines of code and make sure you have the following lines:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Data;
   using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
   using System.Data.OleDb;
   ```
7. Go to the menu Project > Add Reference. On the .NET tab, make sure you select

   ```
   Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
   ```

   and

   ```
   Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
   ```

   Credit to [DotNetMonster](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/05bd45a9-83d6-431c-91a3-aae286f42265/) for the tip.
8. In the

   ```
   public void Main()
   ```

   method, you will see a comment that says

   ```
   // TODO: Add your code here
   ```

   We will replace that line or add the following lines of code. By the way, I am using OLEDB for my data source and data destination.
9. ```
   //Declare variables
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100 cmParams;
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection oleDbConn;

   ConnectionManager cm;
   Int32 strStartDate;
   Int32 strEndDate;
   String startDateSQL = "SELECT StartDate FROM DATE_RANGE_CONTROL";
   String endDateSQL   = "SELECT EndDate FROM DATE_RANGE_CONTROL";


   //Declare and assign Connection manager
   cm = Dts.Connections["YOUR_OLEDB_CONNECTION_MANAGER_NAME"];

   //Set Connection paramters
   cmParams = cm.InnerObject as Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.IDTSConnectionManagerDatabaseParameters100;

   //Instantiate the Oledb connection
   oleDbConn = cmParams.GetConnectionForSchema() as OleDbConnection;
   ```

   Assign the `strStartDate` and `strEndDate` variables, the result of running a function that we will display later. All it does provide an SQL command to the OLEDB connection.

```
        strStartDate = (int)assignSQLCommand(startDateSQL,oleDbConn).ExecuteScalar();
        strEndDate   = (int)assignSQLCommand(endDateSQL, oleDbConn).ExecuteScalar();

        //Assign the startDate and endDate variables the value of the SQL resultset
        Dts.Variables["startDate"].Value = strStartDate;
        Dts.Variables["endDate"].Value   = strEndDate;
```

Declare a variable called `dataSourceSQL` of type string and assign your DataSource SQL code to it. Replace the date range values with the values of the variables above. For me, the code is as follows:

```
    String dataSourceSQL = "SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,TRANSACTION_DATE
    FROM SOURCE_DATABASE_TABLE
    WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '"+Dts.Variables["startDate"].Value +"' AND '"+Dts.Variables["endDate"].Value+"'";
```

Then assign the value of `dataSourceSQL` to your `strDataSourceSQL` package variable

```
    Dts.Variables["strDataSourceSQL"].Value = dataSourceSQL ;
```

Outside the curly brackets of the `public void Main()` method, add the following function we discussed earlier.

```
    public OleDbCommand assignSQLCommand(String SqlCommand, OleDbConnection oledbconn)
    {
        return new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlCommand, oledbconn);
    }
```

Go to the menu Build > Build [script name]. Save it and close the script page. Finally, all that is left is to create a Data Source task. Go to the `Data Flow` tab, drag an OLE DB DB Source to the pane. Right click on the OLE DB Source and choose edit. On the Connections Manager page, select your OLE DB connection manager and on the `Data access mode` choose `SQL command from variable`. In the variable name select `user::strDataSourceSQL`. As long as you set up your script task to run before your data flow, the job is done!

Comment: +1 for contributing your solution!  An alternate approach that would also work uses [SQL Execute Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003(v=sql.110).aspx) with output parameters that are wired to variables. But Dts.Variables will work also.

Comment: Great idea. I will explore that option.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could do that. 
In the OLE DB Source, enter your sql statement and enter ? as the parameter.
click [Parameters...] button and pick your variable from the list